# Xamarin UWP app throws System.MissingFieldException: Field not found: 'Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.StyleProperty'

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I have an app targeting Android, iOS, and UWP. The main xaml page uses a style property in a label, like so:

```
<Label Text="{Binding term}"
   LineBreakMode="WordWrap" 
   Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
   FontSize="24" />
```

This works fine in iOS and Android, but when trying to run in the UWP simulator or locally, I get the error found below. If I remove all style references everything works again...without any styles applied, of course.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work correctly would be appreciated.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.MissingFieldException' in Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll
System.MissingFieldException: Field not found: 'Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.StyleProperty'.
   at SomeApp.Views.ItemsPage.<InitializeComponent>_anonXamlCDataTemplate_1.LoadDataTemplate()
   at Xamarin.Forms.ElementTemplate.CreateContent()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2.ActivateContent(Int32 index, Object item)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2.CreateContent(Int32 index, Object item, Boolean insert)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2.ConvertContent(Int32 startingIndex, IList items, Boolean forceCreate, Boolean setIndex)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2.OnProxyCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy.<>c__DisplayClass33_0.<OnCollectionChanged>b__0()
   at Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy.WeakNotifyProxy.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
   at SomeApp.ViewModels.ItemsViewModel.<ExecuteLoadItemsCommand>d__9.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Please share you style that I could reproduce this issue.

Comment: I believe that your problem is that in your ListItemTextStyle you are mapping a property that does not exist in uwp. The error says it clear: Field not found: 'Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.StyleProperty. You could share the code of your style to check the properties you are using ?